# How to find the frequency of a number,without asking the user to enter the input?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to code a program to find the frequency of a number without asking for the user input.To be clear,I'm looking for an idea where the user doesnot enter the value for which he needs to calculate the frequency,the compiler should default tell the frequency of each number  in the list instead of user giving a number .Below mentioned is my code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

float frequency (int theArray [ ], int number, int x)
 {
int count = 0;
float mount=0.0;
float tot = (float)number;
int u;
int k;
float q,h;

   //   printf("%d",number);

 for (u = 0; u < number; u++)
 {
    if ( theArray[u]==x)
        count++;
 }
  printf ("\nThe frequency of %d in your array is %d ",x,count);

for(k = 0; k< number; k++)
{
    if(theArray[k]==x)

           //count(theArray[k])         
    {       mount++;

    }
  }
  if(mount>1)
    {


    q = mount/tot;


    return q;

    }
   else
  {


   h = mount/tot;

    return h;
    }
  } 


 void main()
   {
   FILE*file = fopen("num.txt","r");
   int integers[100];
   int theArray[100];
   int i=0;
   float e;
   int num;
   int x,k;
   while(fscanf(file,"%d",&num)>0)
   {
    integers[i]=num;
    printf("\n%d",integers[i]);
    i++;
    }

 printf ("\n OK, Thanks! Now What Number Do You Want To Search For Frequency In Your Array? ");
 scanf(" %d", &x);/*Stores Number To Search For Frequency*/
 e =  frequency(integers,i,x); 
printf("\n probability of %d is %f",x,e);
getch();
fclose(file);
     }
```

so my  output as of now is:
   1)  The list of numbers
   2)The frequency of the number occurence
   3)Probability of my number
  instead i'm looking for something that gives the probability and frequency of my number without any
  user input. i.e I'm looking for something like

Output:
  Frequency of this number is ---- and it's probability is---------

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Ani i've already calculated the probability.

Comment: What is the problem in your code? Which number's frequecy and probablity do you want?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this loop will do the trick for u

```
for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == -999) // checking if the number has been counted before or not
        continue;
    temp = array[i]; // take each number from the array one by one
    for(j = 0; j < number; j++) // iterate over the array to check the number of occurences of temp
    {
        if(array[j] == temp) 
        {
            array[j] = -999; // putting -999 at places where the number has already been counted
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("frequency of %d is %d, and probability is %f", temp, count, count/number);
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: ralph what if i want to return probability i mean (count/number) to the main function?

Comment: u will have to store the probabilities in an array and return that array.

Comment: The idea is i have to pass these probabilites to a function called entropy .that calculates the entropy of my file! which i couldn't get

Comment: I'm just trying to pass  count/tot   to another array.and i'm storing the probabilites by iterating it over the size of the input.. it goes something like this for(i=0;i<number;i++){arr[k] = (tot/count); } return arr[k];